# Latin for "recycle"?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, word-request

I'm figuring that if I want to talk about "refurbishing" something, then *renovare* is a pretty good verb to use, or perhaps *reficere* (depending on how beat up it was).

If I want to talk about "reusing" it, then *iterum uti* actually makes a lot of sense.

But how do I talk about "recycling" something? *Ad reversum* or *in se versum mittere*? That seems a little twee.

Answer (score 4):

How about the verb [*circumagere*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2010325)?
The translations include "to drive or turn in a circle, to turn round, to drive around, to produce by going around".
I think "to make something go in a circle" is pretty close to "to recycle".

You might sometimes want to clarify the translation by adding more words, but I believe in most contexts there is little danger of confusion.
(Perhaps you could parse the English "to recycle" as "to ride a bike again", but this ambiguity is not a real issue, is it?)

Ho do these examples sound to you?

> *Haec charta e materia circumacta facta est.*
>   *Nonne hi cumuli quisquiliarum nos ad circumagendum hortantur?*

Comment: Oh, I DO like that. I also learned the word *quisquilia* last week and am delighted to see it used.

Answer (score 3):

**.1.** For metalwork, hardware re-cycling:  Isaiah 2:4
They will beat their swords into plowshares and their spears into pruning hooks (sickles).

> **conflabunt** gladios suos in vomeres et lanceas suas in falces

Micah 4:3
They will hammer their swords into ploughshares and their spears into pruning hooks (garden tools =plough, pick, rake, spade).

> et **concident** gladios suos in vomeres et hastas suas in ligones

**.2.** For refurbishment rather than recycling:To forge anew; or to hammer again as in coin: **recudo. recudere, recudi. recusum.**

> vetera metalla **recudunt,** *Varr.*

**.3.** Or if the refurbishment is spit and polish: **polio, polire, polivi, politum.**

**.4.** For human re-cycling: 1 Corinthians 15:52 
in a flash, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, the dead will be raised imperishable, *and we will be changed.*

> **et nos inmutabimur.**

**.5.** But vertor, versus, "turned into," is a more general term for "recycled as." The corpse (tenth stage of life) says (1300CE):
I have been recycled as dust; Life caught me out.

> **versus sum** in cinerem, Vita me decepit.

Answer (score 1):

How about *ad novum usum aptare*, lit. "adapt for a new use"?

Comment: Hmm. While that's *true* of something recycled (if I put a soda can into the recycling bin, it does get adapted for new use), it's also true of lots of *other* things one could do with it (put it as the crowning glory atop one's Saturnalia tree). I *think* I'm looking for something a little more specific.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Vatican *Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis* uses (in Ecclesiastical Latin):

   > pecúniae male partae collocátio

   (taken from the online subsample of words, found [here](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html), with Italian translation (*riciclaggio* being the world recycling).

   This seems however a rather odd phrase, which could be translated as "the setting up of wrongly born wealth/money"?  No clue how this relates to recycling.
2. The [wikipedia entry](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacyclismus) calls it (as noun; see [discussion](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputatio:Anacyclismus)):

   > Anacyclismus, seu regyratio

   The first term seems to have been proposed by [Stephanus Berard](http://boreoccidentales.com/english/about-stephanus-berard/) (again, see discussion page). This seems to be originated from the term [Anacyclic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anacyclic), which means palindromic, which itself comes from Ancient Greek [*palindromos*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palindrome), meaning "running back again".
3. The [discussion page](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputatio:Anacyclismus) of the above wiki entry also mentions the following (as noun):

   > ad utilitatem redactio, ad usum iteratum aptatio

   The website says this is also a translation from the *Lexicon ...*